# Mysql sum multiple column values with date condition

Tags: mysql

I have a client table with below columns which have data of every day purchase of every client month wise.

```
ID|MONTH|DAY1|DAY2|DAY3|DAY4|..........|DAY31
1 |  4  | 10 | 20 | 0  | 15 |..........|10
2 |  4  | 20 | 30 | 23 | 7  |..........| 5
1 |  5  | 5  | 10 | 20 | 4  |..........| 20
1 |  6  | 12 | 0  | 10 | 5  |..........| 10
2 |  6  | 10 | 10 | 5  | 10 |..........| 5
```

Now i want to find the total qty purchased by every client between 15/4/2015 to 15/6/2015.

I am new to mysql, so have no idea how to move forward.

Thanks in advance

Comment: should normalise your structure

Comment: can you change the table's structure? this is an awful way to store this kind of data

Comment: Sorry, the table is being used by my company for some time are they are quiet happy with it

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use a column for every day of the month to store a value. But sometimes we are stuck on bad data formats, here's how you can get the count you need:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(qty)
FROM (
  SELECT
    ID,
    MAKEDATE(2015,1) + INTERVAL (month-1) MONTH AS dt,
    DAY1 AS qry
  FROM yourtable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ID,
    MAKEDATE(2015,1) + INTERVAL (month-1) MONTH AS dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY,
    DAY2 AS qry
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ID,
    MAKEDATE(2015,1) + INTERVAL (month-1) MONTH AS dt + INTERVAL 2 DAY,
    DAY3 AS qry
  FROM yourtable
  UNION ALL
  ...
  until day 31
  ...
) s
WHERE
  dt>='2015-04-15' AND dt<='2015-06-15'
GROUP BY ID
```

I'm using a subquery to normalize the data structure, then I'm doing the counts on the outer query, a simple where clause and group by will give the results that you need.

Comment: Thank You for your reply...but I tried the below query and it worked SELECT ID
 SUM(
CASE MONTH 
WHEN 1 THEN 0
WHEN 2 THEN 0
WHEN 3 THEN 0
WHEN 4 THEN DAY15+DAY16......+DAY31
WHEN 5 THEN DAY1+DAY2+....+DAY31
WHEN 6 THEN Day1+DAY2+.....+DAY15
WHEN 7 THEN 0
WHEN 8 THEN 0
WHEN 9 THEN 0
WHEN 10 THEN 0
WHEN 11 THEN 0
WHEN 12 THEN 0
END) TARGET
FROM TABLE
WHERE MONTH in (4,5,6)
GROUP BY ID

I can change the case statement through script as per my requirement.
THANK YOU